# Would a perfectly collimated laser beam have a flat intensity distribution?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, light-emitting-diodes, intensity

I'm trying to simulate a collimated laser beam in some FORTRAN and am wondering about the intensity distribution of a perfectly collimated beam: would it be a flat distribution (equal intensity across the beam) or it would be more of a gaussian? I know that a perfectly collimated beam wouldn't disperse, but would this translate to equal intensity across the beam?

Comment: Well, it can't be perfectly collimated, so I'm not sure the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collimation means that all pencil ("bundle") of light rays emitted from one specific **point** in the object plane is "translated" by the collimator to a pencil of rays that have a specific **angle**.

In this case, the object is the output surface of the laser cavity or the output of an optical fiber.

Imagine you have a **point light source**, then a collimator could create a beam that consists of rays of **only one angle**, and a homogeneous intensity distribution would be possible. Such a light source doesn't exist, though.

Additionally, diffraction laws make it impossible to create a light source that emits light at only one angle, so even if you'd try to eliminate the need for a collimator by fixing the problem at the source, that's not possible.

By the way, the best physically possible light source (i.e. with minimum divergence) actually [has a Gaussian intensity profile](https://www.edmundoptics.de/knowledge-center/application-notes/lasers/gaussian-beam-propagation/) (in far-field approximation) and its divergence angle $\theta$ is

$$
\theta = \frac \lambda {\pi w_0},
$$

where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $w_0$ is the beam waist (i.e. the emitter diameter or the collimator output diameter, depending on which divergence angle you're interested in).

Answer (score 0):

"Top hat" optics can provide a nearly flat intensity distribution across a beam.  A Gaussian beam is nearly flat near its center, so simply passing it through a circular aperture yields a nearly flat beam.  A beam that is slightly nonuniform can be corrected by passing it through a customized gray-level filter to reduce intensity in the high-intensity regions.  In practice, you can create a beam with intensity pattern and/or phase pattern you want, using a combination of phase and intensity spatial light modulators.